# Проблемы с модальным окном

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://prntscr.com/kykulc
При нажатии на кнопку "заказать звонок появляется " затемнение, но основной блок и кнопка, продолжают подсвечиваться. Пробовал задавать диву с классом overflow  z-index:1;, но после этого какой бы z-index я не задавал модальному окну - оно не появляется. 
Ссылка на сайт: http://mkf24.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в css файл условие ещё такое. И попап появится.

```css
.popup {
display: block;
z-index: 100;
}
.overlay {
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: я так полагаю ему еще нужно что бы затемнение появилось. Скорее всего не там попап вызывает.

Comment: @НикитаРязанов знач так.

Comment: Все заработало!Спасибо!